# Slow snap startup caused by an xdg-desktop-portal service (xdg-document-portal), no fuse 3.12, how to fix?

Tags: snap, 23.10, xdg, fuse

Any snap seems to start slowly. When running with `--trace-exec` I see the following message at the beginning of the logs:

```
2024/01/05 18:13:22.350176 cmd_run.go:1055: WARNING: cannot start document portal: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.portal.Documents': timed out (service_start_timeout=120000ms)
```

it seems this is related to something called xdg-desktop-portal. Some people have fixed it by identifying an issue with the ownership of a directory found under `.local/share/flatpak`. I don't have such a directory.

Further investigation led me to the xdg-document-portal service. In my case, it's unable to start successfully:

```
$ systemctl --user status xdg-document-portal.service
× xdg-document-portal.service - flatpak document portal service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/xdg-document-portal.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2024-01-05 18:19:54 GMT; 1s ago
    Process: 9581 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/xdg-document-portal (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 9581 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 2ms

Jan 05 18:19:54 CSLLAP- systemd[4067]: Starting xdg-document-portal.service - flatpak document portal service...
Jan 05 18:19:54 CSLLAP- xdg-document-portal[9581]: /usr/libexec/xdg-document-portal: /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfuse3.so.3: version `FUSE_3.12' not found (required by /usr/libexec/xdg-document-portal)
Jan 05 18:19:54 CSLLAP- systemd[4067]: xdg-document-portal.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 05 18:19:54 CSLLAP- systemd[4067]: xdg-document-portal.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 05 18:19:54 CSLLAP- systemd[4067]: Failed to start xdg-document-portal.service - flatpak document portal service.
```

With the chief issue being:

```
Jan 05 18:19:54 CSLLAP- xdg-document-portal[9581]: /usr/libexec/xdg-document-portal: /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfuse3.so.3: version `FUSE_3.12' not found (required by /usr/libexec/xdg-document-portal)
```

I don't know what fuse is but I seem to have a later version of it

```
$ sudo apt install libfuse3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libfuse3-dev is already the newest version (3.14.0-4).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

Does xdg-document-portal absolutely depend on fuse 3.12? What can I do to fix this? Can I stop snaps from relying on this service to run?

OS details:

```
[~]$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.10
Release:    23.10
Codename:   mantic
[~]$ uname -a
Linux CSLLAP- 6.5.0-14-generic #14-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Nov 14 14:59:49 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[~]$
```

Edit: a workaround is to just install fuse [3.12](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/releases/tag/fuse-3.12.0) using the [installation instructions](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse) on the repo page. But I'd love to understand what's going on better.

Answer (score 1):

After rebooting Ubuntu 23.10 I have to wait 2 minutes after which everything works fine. Opening the terminal, nautilus, etc before that time is very slow.

An online search seems to point `xdg-document-portal.service` as the culprit. There are *solutions* where it's removed but since I don't know what it's for I didn't want to go that route.

```shell
$ systemctl is-enabled --user xdg-desktop-portal
static

$ systemctl mask --user xdg-desktop-portal
Created symlink /home/daniel/.config/systemd/user/xdg-desktop-portal.service → /dev/null.

$ systemctl is-enabled --user xdg-desktop-portal
masked
```

By masking it (middle command above, no sudo) the unit is pointed to /dev/null and can't be activated.

After reboot the delay is gone and opening the terminal, etc works as fast as expected.

---

**Note 1**: Strangely, after reboot the service is shown as active and back to `static`:

```
$ systemctl is-enabled --user xdg-document-portal
static
```

I don't know why that is but I'm no longer having slowness issues.

---

**Note 2**: My issue seems to be different than yours since I don't have problems with FUSE. I don't have `libfuse3-dev` installed. I only installed Mantic last week so maybe the problem you were having has been fixed by a system upgrade and mine is something else entirely. But I'm leaving what I did here in case others are going through the same difficulties.

---

**Update 1:** With `xdg-desktop-portal` masked I don't have slowness issues at boot but it causes other problems -- at least one I'm aware of. In Firefox (snap), when I trying to insert a PDF into OneNote it doesn't work. The local file picker simply doesn't show up. Unmasking `xdg-desktop-portal` and restarting the service makes the file picker in FF work again.